# Custom Connector in Power Automate that calls Azure OpenAI Chat model

Tags: azure, power-automate, openai-api, azure-openai

I have created a Custom Connector in Power Automate that calls Azure OpenAI Chat model

[image]

but while testing the connector i get the following response

[image]

How do i solve it?

I wanted to get the response from Chat Model in AzureOpenAI in which i would be using in my flow